# Use facebook Like button without any image being scraped from my site

Tags: facebook-like, addthis

I don't want any image to be displayed on Facebook when users of my site click the 'Like' button I've added using addthis

Is there any way to configure the Like button so that it has no Image attached to the post which is created when the Like button is used?

Answer (score 0):

og:image is a required field - if you don't want a visible image, just use a monochrome image instead?